# Getting 'Cannot implicitly convert type' errors but can't figure out why

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two files on my Razor pages project. One is **AllTracks.htmlcs.cs** and **AllAlbums.htmlcs.cs**.

They share mostly the same code apart from some small differences, although, on my AllTracks.html.cs page, I am getting the following error:

```
Pages\AllTracks.htmlcs.cs(25,26): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<namespaceHere.Album>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<namespaceHere.Tracks>'
```

I have tried to debug this, I have tried changing variable names and looking around but I cannot for the life of me figure how why I am being thrown this error, could somebody look at my code and let me know why this is happening?

AllTracks.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using namespaceHere;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace namespaceHere
{
    public class AllTracksModel : PageModel
    {
        DatabaseContext _Context;
        public AllTracksModel(DatabaseContext databasecontext)
        {
            _Context = databasecontext;
        }
 
        public List<Track> TracksList { get; set; }
        public void OnGet(int? id)
        {
        var data = (from album in _Context.albums
                            where album.AlbumId == id
                            select album).ToList(); 
 
            TracksList = data;  
        }

        public ActionResult OnGetDelete(int? id)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                        var data = _Context.tracks.ToList(); 
                            _Context.Remove(data);
                            _Context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToPage("/AllTracks");
        }
    }
}
```

AllAlbum.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using namespaceHere;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace namespaceHere
{
    public class AllAlbumModel : PageModel
    {
        DatabaseContext _Context;
        public AllAlbumModel(DatabaseContext databasecontext)
        {
            _Context = databasecontext;
        }
 
        public List<Album> AlbumList { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
        var data = _Context.albums.Include(x => x.Artist).ToList(); 
 
            AlbumList = data;
        }

        public ActionResult OnGetDelete(int? id)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                var data = (from album in _Context.albums
                            where album.AlbumId == id
                            select album).SingleOrDefault();

                            _Context.Remove(data);
                            _Context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToPage("/AllAlbum");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @DonnieBerry, `asp.net-mvc` is different framework with `asp.net-core-mvc`. Same goes with `entity-framework` and `entity-framework-core`.

Comment: The exception message is quite clear.  In your `OnGet` method for `AllTracksModel` class, you are supposed to query `Track` but you are querying `Album`. Hope this hint will help you to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Which line are you referring to? I can't see where I am querying 'Album' on the AllTracksModel class

Comment: Hi @Donnie, check `OnGet` method for `AllTracksModel` class. Your LINQ query is using `Albums` based on the source code in your question.

Comment: Hi there, sorry, I am new to Razor pages. I thought that by using "_Context.tracks" would access the tracks table, when I want to use the Album table for this specific use case. Is that not correct?

Comment: Hi @Donnie, I think you should add the reason why you query `Album` in your `OnGet` for `AllTracksModel` and what is the expected result you tried to achieve. And possible to attach both `Album` and `Track` table schemas for reference. Thank you.